# Java - Call static method of another class from main

Tags: java, encryption, variable-assignment, static-methods

I'm trying to implement a simple encrypt/decrypt from the javax.crypto library but I'm stuck trying to call the method from an implementation of an AES class I have found on github https://gist.github.com/bricef/2436364.

```
public class AES {
  static String IV = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";

  public static byte[] encrypt(String plainText, String encryptionKey) throws Exception {
    //..code
    return cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  }
}
```

I am then trying to call the method from my main method in another class and assign its return value to a variable using an instance like so;

```
AES aes = new AES();
byte[] encrypt = aes.encrypt(msg, key);
```

I get unhandled exception type Exception.

I have also tried it this way;

```
byte[] encrypt = AES.encrypt(msg, key);
```

How do I call this method and assign the return value to a variable which I can then use to do lots of other cool stuff?

I know this question is simple but some explanation on how you do these types of calls/assignments in Java would be great.

Comment: Xan you post the Stacktrace of the exception please.

Comment: Handle the exception. The error is telling exactly what's wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to AES class looks perfectly right, since it is public, you create an instance properly and then call a public method on it.  Probably your Exception happens due to some problem inside `encrypt` method.  Please surround it with a

```
try { 
  AES aes = new AES();
  byte[] encrypt = aes.encrypt(msg, key);
} 
catch(Exception e) { 
   e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

block, since it will give you accurate information about what is broken.  Even better, get yourself a programming environment with a debugger and just execute your program step by step inside the `encrypt` method in order to find out where is the problem.  Have fun with java! :)